# flutter_bloc (emit was called after an event handler completed normally

Tags: flutter, flutter-bloc

So, I was working with Django rest framework creating my APIs and all.
And i wanted to check if I can get the response from the backend.
So, I was able to get the response. But I saw some issues on the debug console. Please help me figure out the problem.
This is what I received on the Debug Console.

```
Restarted application in 1,314ms.
I/flutter ( 1751): {"token":"0d15f2d45f11869174395d623c066080bd2ade52"}
E/flutter ( 1751): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:bloc/src/bloc.dart': Failed assertion: line 232 pos 7: '!_isCompleted':
E/flutter ( 1751):
E/flutter ( 1751):
E/flutter ( 1751): emit was called after an event handler completed normally.
E/flutter ( 1751): This is usually due to an unawaited future in an event handler.
E/flutter ( 1751): Please make sure to await all asynchronous operations with event handlers
E/flutter ( 1751): and use emit.isDone after asynchronous operations before calling emit() to
E/flutter ( 1751): ensure the event handler has not completed.
E/flutter ( 1751):
E/flutter ( 1751):   **BAD**
E/flutter ( 1751):   on<Event>((event, emit) {
E/flutter ( 1751):     future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
E/flutter ( 1751):   });
E/flutter ( 1751):
E/flutter ( 1751):   **GOOD**
E/flutter ( 1751):   on<Event>((event, emit) async {
E/flutter ( 1751):     await future.whenComplete(() => emit(...));
E/flutter ( 1751):   });
E/flutter ( 1751):
E/flutter ( 1751): #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:46:39)
E/flutter ( 1751): #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:36:5)
E/flutter ( 1751): #2      _Emitter.call
E/flutter ( 1751): #3      new LoginFormBloc.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
E/flutter ( 1751): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 1751):
Reloaded 1 of 746 libraries in 1,055ms.
```

Here's my source code:

**login_form_event.dart**

```dart
part of 'login_form_bloc.dart';

@freezed
class LoginFormEvent with _$LoginFormEvent {
  const factory LoginFormEvent.emailChanged(String emailStr) = _EmailChanged;
  const factory LoginFormEvent.passwordChanged(String passwordStr) =
      _PasswordChanged;
  const factory LoginFormEvent.loggedIn() = _LoggedIn;
}
```

**login_form_state.dart**

```dart
part of 'login_form_bloc.dart';

@freezed
class LoginFormState with _$LoginFormState {
  const factory LoginFormState({
    required EmailAddress emailAddress,
    required Password password,
    required bool isSubmitting,
    required bool showErrorMessages,
    required Option<Either<AuthFailure, TokenValue>> authFailureOrSuccessOption,
  }) = _LoginFormState;

  factory LoginFormState.initial() => LoginFormState(
        emailAddress: EmailAddress(''),
        password: Password(''),
        isSubmitting: false,
        showErrorMessages: false,
        authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
      );
}
```

**login_form_bloc.dart**

```dart
class LoginFormBloc extends Bloc<LoginFormEvent, LoginFormState> {
  LoginFormBloc(this._getAuthInfo) : super(LoginFormState.initial()) {
    on<LoginFormEvent>(
      (event, emit) {
        event.map(
          emailChanged: (e) {
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                emailAddress: EmailAddress(e.emailStr),
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          passwordChanged: (e) {
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                password: Password(e.passwordStr),
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          loggedIn: (e) async {
            final isEmailValid = state.emailAddress.value.isRight();
            final isPasswordValid = state.password.value.isRight();

            Either<AuthFailure, TokenValue>? loginFailureOrSuccess;

            if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
              emit(
                state.copyWith(
                  isSubmitting: true,
                  authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
                ),
              );
              loginFailureOrSuccess = await _getAuthInfo(
                Params(
                  emailAddress: state.emailAddress,
                  password: state.password,
                ),
              );
            }

         //The error is pointed to this emit below
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                isSubmitting: false,
                showErrorMessages: true,
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: optionOf(loginFailureOrSuccess),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  final GetAuthToken _getAuthInfo;
}
```

The error is pointed on 2nd emit inside loggedIn event handler.

Comment: What's up with the map method? Why not use the normal `on<Event>` notation, it will probably fix the issue... If you don't want to use the normal `on` method, could you show the implementation of the `map` method?

Comment: The map method is there because I have used unions offered by freezed package.

Comment: @h8moss see the updated post. Maybe that will help.

Comment: The issue has been solved now.

Comment: I see, happy to hear the issue got fixed

Answer (score 11):

All I had to do was add an `await` keyword before calling `event.map()` and mark the function with `async` as shown below.
Also, I explicitly mentioned what my individual event handlers should return. In this case, it was `FutureOr<void>`.

```dart
class LoginFormBloc extends Bloc<LoginFormEvent, LoginFormState> {
  LoginFormBloc(this._getAuthInfo) : super(LoginFormState.initial()) {
    on<LoginFormEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        await event.map<FutureOr<void>>(  // Added an await in this line
          emailChanged: (e) {
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                emailAddress: EmailAddress(e.emailStr),
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          passwordChanged: (e) {
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                password: Password(e.passwordStr),
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          loggedIn: (e) async {
            final isEmailValid = state.emailAddress.value.isRight();
            final isPasswordValid = state.password.value.isRight();

            Either<AuthFailure, TokenValue>? loginFailureOrSuccess;

            if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
              emit(
                state.copyWith(
                  isSubmitting: true,
                  authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
                ),
              );
              loginFailureOrSuccess = await _getAuthInfo(
                Params(
                  emailAddress: state.emailAddress,
                  password: state.password,
                ),
              );
            }
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                isSubmitting: false,
                showErrorMessages: true,
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: optionOf(loginFailureOrSuccess),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  final GetAuthToken _getAuthInfo;
}
```

Alternatively, we can also replace the `map` method with `when` in the event handling section (which I prefer to use over `map` in scenarios like above). Then, the code would look like this:

```dart
class LoginFormBloc extends Bloc<LoginFormEvent, LoginFormState> {
  LoginFormBloc(this._getAuthInfo) : super(LoginFormState.initial()) {
    on<LoginFormEvent>(
      (event, emit) async {
        await event.when<FutureOr<void>>(  // Replace map with when
          emailChanged: (emailStr) {  // Can directly pass String instead of _EmailChanged object
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                emailAddress: EmailAddress(emailStr),  // Can directly pass emailStr as shown
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          passwordChanged: (passwordStr) {
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                password: Password(passwordStr),
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
              ),
            );
          },
          loggedIn: () async {
            final isEmailValid = state.emailAddress.value.isRight();
            final isPasswordValid = state.password.value.isRight();

            Either<AuthFailure, TokenValue>? loginFailureOrSuccess;

            if (isEmailValid && isPasswordValid) {
              emit(
                state.copyWith(
                  isSubmitting: true,
                  authFailureOrSuccessOption: none(),
                ),
              );
              loginFailureOrSuccess = await _getAuthInfo(
                Params(
                  emailAddress: state.emailAddress,
                  password: state.password,
                ),
              );
            }
            emit(
              state.copyWith(
                isSubmitting: false,
                showErrorMessages: true,
                authFailureOrSuccessOption: optionOf(loginFailureOrSuccess),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
  final GetAuthToken _getAuthInfo;
}
```

Note: `when` comes from [freezed package](https://pub.dev/packages/freezed). It is not a native component of the dart language.

Comment: I was exactly looking for this, thanks for posting the answer.